# 赤らめる 大それた rule for reading

Tags: readings

> [大]{だい}それた

On’yomi before hiragana in a word looks special.
Are there any other examples?
If any, how can I know whether it is kun’yomi or on’yomi?
Like:

> [赤]{あか}らめた

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On’yomi before hiragana are exceptional cases in Japanese. Most of those words occur when a conjugation of the verb する is followed after On’yomi, such as:

> [信]{しん}じる,
>   [愛]{あい}する,
>   [論]{ろん}じる,
>   [発]{はっ}する,
>   [感]{かん}じる,
>   [辞]{じ}する,
>   [私]{し}する

However, [大]{だい}それた is not included even in this type.
I know several other examples:

> [大]{たい}した,
>   [単]{たん}なる,
>   [当]{とう}の,
>   [聖]{せい}なる

But probably they are quite special. I don't know this is related, but at least examples above, these are categorized into a special word class called pre-noun adjectival ([連体詞]{れんたいし}). It is said that there are few words belonging to this word class.